Showing a subset is dense in the symmetric tensor product of a Hilbert space
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathcal{H}^{\odot p}$ denote the $p$-fold symmetric tensor product. I want to show that the set
$$U=\text{Span}\{u^{\otimes p} : u\in \mathcal{H}\}$$
is dense in $\mathcal{H}^{\odot p}$. If $(e_n)$ is a basis of $\mathcal{H}$, my hunch is that you can show the claim by showing that for any $i_1,\dots,i_p\in \mathbb{N}$, you can express
$$\sum_{\sigma} e_{i_1}\otimes\cdots \otimes e_{i_p}$$
as a linear combination of elements from $U$, where the sum runs over all permutations.
My idea for this is to consider  expressions like
$$(a_1e_{i_1}+\cdots+a_pe_{i_p})^{\otimes p}\in U,$$
for suitable coefficients $a_1,\dots,a_p\in \mathbb{R}$. I have checked in some special cases that this works, but I can't wrap my head around how to choose the coefficients in general.

@Masacroso Yes, it is equipped with the same inner product.

(This is basically copied from an answer I wrote to a different question.)
$$\mathrm{Sym}(h_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes h_p) = \frac{1}{2^pp!} \sum_{(i_1, \cdots, i_p) \in \{ \pm1\}^p} [(\prod_{j=1}^p i_j)(i_1h_1 + \cdots + i_ph_p)^{\otimes p}]$$
Where $\mathrm{Sym}$ is defined, as usual, by,
$$\mathrm{Sym}(h_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes h_p) = \frac{1}{p!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_p} h_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes h_{\sigma(p)}$$

Wow, cool! No wonder the proof eluded me!
